# Mac addresses of all devices on LAN in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, networking

Does anyone know how to use Ruby to grab a list of the MAC addresses of all the devices on the local network? Preferably as quick a response as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute your actual IP range for the X's

```
ping -c 2 x.x.x.255
```

And then parse the results of an

```
arp -a
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work very well cross-platform, don't suppose you know if Ruby has equivalent commands?

Comment: Ruby's ping implementation does not use ICMP and there is no built-in ARP library that I'm aware of, so probably not.

Comment: All the currently common operating systems I can think of will have the 'ping' and 'arp' commands if they have an IP stack. The command parameters would be slightly different, however (e.g. in Linux 'ping -c 1 ...' sends only one packet, where the Windows equivalent would be 'ping -n 1 ...'; and with NIX the command 'arp' will show the whole table, whereas with Windows you need to do 'arp -a').

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [arp-scan](http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools-resources/security-tools/arp-scan)

There is also a nice arp-scan gem [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/arp_scan) that simply wraps the binary.